# How to build this regex

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to build a regex that fulfills these requirements, but I am not sure how to do it. I tried with `[A-Z][a-z]+[,][ ][A-Z][a-z]+[ ][A-Z][.]` but it's not doing what I want. I need some help.

**Requirements**

Last, First M.

- Last - must begin with a capital letter and be followed by one more lower case letters.
- First - must begin with a capital letter and be followed by one or more lower case letters.
- M. - must be a single capital letter followed by a period (.). This part (including the preceding space) is optional.*

Examples of valid accepted strings are:

```
"Davis, Mike"
"Leppla, David A."
```

Invalid examples are:

```
"D, Mike"
"L, David"
"Smith, Joe "    
           ^ with an extra space on the end
"smith, Mike"    
"Jo, Fr a."
```

Comment: Do trim on input string and try with [A-Z][a-z]+,\s[A-Z][a-z]+[^\s](\s[A-Z].)? as the regex

Comment: what will trim do?

Comment: String which you want to check with regex

Comment: I checked this regex on regexr.com and I don't think its working

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: [A-Z][a-z]+[,][ ][A-Z][a-z]+[ ][A-Z][.]

Comment: In my post I added another one and would appreciate any help with that too

Comment: I rolled back that edit; ask one question per question. If you get help with this one you should probably be able to figure out the broader picture at the same time. Note that regexr and friends use a different regex dialect than Bash. Your attempt doesn't make the final initial optional.

Comment: You almost got it. Starting from your own regex you just need to make last part of the pattern optional. `[ ][A-Z][.]` should become `([ ][A-Z][.])?`. To ensure it won't allow for trailing spaces, you also should add proper anchoring to your regex, then becoming `^[A-Z][a-z]+[,][ ][A-Z][a-z]+([ ][A-Z][.])?$`.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+,\s(?:[A-Z][a-z]+\ |[A-Z]\.\ )*(?:[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]\.)$
```

[See this Demo](https://regex101.com/r/76ZUPq/1)